# Does writing fiction with world history based around Allah amount to shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, books

*My question is*: I have written an online book, and realised that for the setting of that world (wrote it in a different world medieval setting), I had the world history based around Allah, but something else.  Does this counts as a minor shirk?

As a note, I do not believe at all that any other God but Allah exists, and nor do my readers believe in the God as it is published on a fiction site for self taught Authors, so it's all purpose was the building and logic of the world in the book.

EDIT:

I have decided to continue the story after much thought, it is an ongoing story at the moment with quite a large fanbase, but I have also decided to change some parts of the earlier story and the history of the world so there isn't a 'God'

I will be referring to it as something else that will conflict less with Islam, and I thank the brother that helped with the solution

Answer (score -1):

First i would say it is a confusion from question that whether you made up the story or it is a history book. So i will try to cover both aspects.

1. If it is a history book telling only the history and beliefs of that time. than their is nothing to worry about.
 2. If you have made up the story based on the setting having false God.
 In this case have a look at these links hope things will be clear:
https://islamqa.info/en/163469
https://islamqa.info/en/6044
And i believe you are not doing any shirk or kuffr. But you should not make stories like this and be in safe zone.
Allah knows best.